# Copying of Time Machine backup at 127%

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine

I am trying to copy pre-existing backups from an older 2TB drive to a new 5TB drive.

Given that I am on macOS Catalina, I simply copied in Finder using command-C on the Backups.backupdb folder and pasted using command-V.

Last night, it reached 1.44 / 1.44 TB but the copying 0 items dialog remained with ETA of 5 seconds.

I let it keep running overnight, and this morning, it is now at 1.85 / 1.85 TB with an ETA of 5 seconds.

Given that the old 2TB drive has 160GB of free space, I don’t understand what is happening! I thought that macOS 10.13.4 fixed the issue with hard links.

Can you please tell me what is happening and what steps I should take now to get the files correctly copied?

**EDIT:** The phantom copying stopped within an hour of posting this but I still don’t understand what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a 'golden rule' for copying Time Machine & I *think* "copy/paste" might break it.
*Use the Finder*.

Finder knows how to do this task. Almost nothing else ever does. All other methods fail to correctly identify all the hard links & you end up copying terrabytes of useless duplicates.

Simple Steps…

1. Switch off Time Machine.
2. Drag the backups.backupdb folder to the root of your new HFS+ drive.
3. When done, set Time Machine to the new drive then re-enable.

A more comprehensive guid can be seen at [How-To Geek - How to Migrate a Time Machine Backup to Another Drive](https://www.howtogeek.com/335090/how-to-migrate-a-time-machine-backup-to-another-drive/)

Note: This all changes with Big Sur & later on APFS drives - which I have no direct experience with, as yet.

Comment: I’m on Catalina so APFS doesn’t apply for my individual case. I used Finder to copy-paste - did not dragging it result in the phantom copying? I don’t understand that. In any case, I’ve edited the question with a status update. What should I do now?

Comment: All I can guess is it was setting all the links in place. Never done it that way so I've no better guess.